# UPDATE rows and SET ordering depending on level and parent

Tags: mysql, mariadb, update

I'm trying to write a small UPDATE query that makes sure all rows are reordered considering the parent_id.

Needs to work under MySQL 5.6 / MariaDB 10

This is a [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6pf4V4nZBJ7AVbpRG11vcC/1) made for testing.

So this is prior reordering:

| id | ordering | level | parent_id | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26 | 2 | 1 | 1 | tools |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 1 | plugins |
| 20 | 4 | 2 | 2 | plugins/p1 |
| 22 | 5 | 2 | 2 | plugins/system |
| 23 | 6 | 3 | 22 | plugins/system/s1 |
| 24 | 7 | 3 | 22 | plugins/system/s2 |
| 25 | 8 | 3 | 22 | plugins/system/s3 |
| 21 | 9 | 2 | 2 | plugins/p2 |
| 27 | 10 | 2 | 26 | tools/f1 |

and this would be after:

| id | ordering | level | parent_id | title |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 26 | 2 | 1 | 1 | tools |
| 27 | 3 | 2 | 26 | tools/f1 |
| 2 | 4 | 1 | 1 | plugins |
| 20 | 5 | 2 | 2 | plugins/p1 |
| 21 | 6 | 2 | 2 | plugins/p2 |
| 22 | 7 | 2 | 2 | plugins/system |
| 23 | 8 | 3 | 22 | plugins/system/s1 |
| 24 | 9 | 3 | 22 | plugins/system/s2 |
| 25 | 10 | 3 | 22 | plugins/system/s3 |

This is a SELECT that creates the correct new reordering in column `rn` :

```
SELECT f1.id, f1.title, f2.rn FROM folders f1
    JOIN
        (

            select  id, title,@rowNumber := @rowNumber + 1 AS rn
            from    (select * from folders 
                    order by  parent_id, id) folders,
                    (select @pv := '1') i1,
                    (select @rowNumber := '0') i2
            where   find_in_set(parent_id, @pv) > 0
            and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id)
    ) f2 ON f1.id = f2.id
```

When i try to use it within an UPDATE statement nothing gets updated:

```
UPDATE folders f1
    JOIN
        (
            select  id, folder, @rowNumber := @rowNumber + 1 AS rn
            from    (select * from folders 
                    order by  parent_id, id) folders,
                    (select @pv := '1') i1,
                    (select @rowNumber := '0') i2
            where   find_in_set(parent_id, @pv) > 0
            and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id)
        ) f2 ON f2.id = f1.id
SET f1.ordering = f2.rn
```

This was another try:

```
UPDATE folders f1, (
            select  id, folder, @rowNumber := @rowNumber + 1 AS rn
            from    (select * from folders 
                    order by  parent_id, id) folders,
                    (select @pv := '1') i1,
                    (select @rowNumber := '0') i2
            where   find_in_set(parent_id, @pv) > 0
            and     @pv := concat(@pv, ',', id)
        ) f2
SET f1.ordering = f2.rn
WHERE f1.id = f2.id
```

Comment: It's restricted to MySQL 5.6

Comment: When you work with user-defined variables then you **MUST** a) have only one source table (and one subquery for variables initialization) b) have ORDER BY clause which' expression provides rows uniqueness. If you have nested subqueries then each nested subquery on each level must have such ORDER BY.

Comment: fiddle opened on the tenth attempt... check does it is safe for you: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=2283e3944d7e64f1734ebd89aabb85ff If not then explain the algorithm of enumeration (desired ordering) in details.

Comment: I will check it out completely tomorrow, but the ordering in your query leads to lost rows.  if id 26 "tools" is ordering 1 (first place) it should stay there and not be last after reordering. what should happen in that case is id 27 "tools/f1" should be placed after id 26 (ordering 2) and everything else after that.

Comment: You have changed the data (prior to reordering - but forget to alter the fiddle).

Comment: @Akina the fiddle is fine. after reordering the row with id 27 should be after id 2 ordered.